# ContentProvider UriMatcher doesn't match Uri

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've created a ContentProvider for my SQLiteDatabase and the Uri that I'm using is not being matched by UriMatcher. In my ContentProvider I have these global variables:

```
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.MyProject.project.MyContentProvider";
private static final String TABLE_BASEPATH = "MyTable_tbl";
public static final Uri My_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_BASEPATH);
public static final int EVERYTHING = 100;
public static final int FILTERED = 110;
```

Then, I have this UriMatcher:

```
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {    
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_BASEPATH, EVERYTHING);    
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_BASEPATH + "/#", FILTERED);
    }
```

In my Activity, I have:

```
MyContentProvider mycontentProvider = new MyContentProvider ();
    mycontentProvider .delete(MY_URI, null, null);
```

In my SQLiteDatabase, I have:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASETABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_STITCHNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_USES + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_VIDEOID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_INSTR
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_LEVEL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CHART
            + " TEXT NOT NULL)");

}
```

where DATABASETABLE is a global variable in my SQLiteDatabase. It is assigned a value like so:

```
private static final String DATABASETABLE = "MyTable_tbl";
```

In my ContentProvider's delete method, the first thing I do is:

```
int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
```

This is what I've got in my manifest, inside the application tags:

```
<provider
    android:authorities="com.MyProject.project.MyContentProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:name="com.MyProject.project.MyContentProvider">        
</provider>
```

This returns uriType = -1. Why? What's wrong with how I'm constructing my Uri?

Comment: I dont understand 100%, but I see that there is a discrepancy in some variable names:My_URI and MY_URI. Maybe this is a problem? Maybe MY_URI is declared elsewhere?

Comment: I suggest using the debugger

Comment: Well, no, that's just a typo on my part. But your comment did make me go back and double-check everything and I found that AUTHORITY in my Activity was incorrect, and that was where I was passing the constructed Uri from. I fixed it and now the Uri is matched correctly. So thank you Tanja! Of course, now there's another problem, but that's for another thread.